# BlackBerry code signing problem in Eclipse

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I received the signing keys from RIM and installed via the Eclipse Plugin for BlackBerry.  After I install the new keys,and then go to the Blackberry Java Signing tool, I can see the `import existing key` option is deactivated.

Where can I find `sigtool.db` and `signtool.csk` files?

How do I sign code for a particular application from Eclipse 3.5 Galileo?

Answer (score 2):

sigtool.db and signtool.csk files can be found in C:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde\vmTools

Please go through the "[How and When to Sign](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/How-and-When-to-Sign/ta-p/442779)" document from blackberry

Answer (score 0):

Code singing can be little difficult with eclipse. I had the same problem. Solution is:
goto the eclipse root directory and locate **SignatureTool.jar** :
**\yourEclipseDir\plugins\net.rim.ejde\vmTools\SignatureTool.jar** 
run SignatureTool.jar file for code signing.